# service name & methods name for particular service for infoservice in google adwords

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I need a help in Google Adwords.

I need all services name in dropdown which are in google adwords v200909.
and also need drop down methods name for particular service which i select from Services dropdown because i have form for infoservice in which i select apiUsageType,Servicename,Method name,max date,min date,operators and click on submit button then infoService api called and give me result.

So, is there any method for finding servicename,methodname for particular that service name,operators,apiUsageType? or is there any process to find it please tell me.

I want code in php.

Answer (score 0):

The available services and method are available in the AdWords API documentation:

http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/